# Intersection of line with discrete hypercubes in n-dimensional space

Tags: discrete-geometry

I am looking for a method to determine the hypercubes that intersect a line between two points in a high dimensional space. I think what I want is the supercover of a line in high dimensional space. For example, if we are working in a 5D bounded space and have points P and Q with coordinates (p1, p2, p3, p4, p5) and (q1, q2, q3, q4, q5), I want to know which points with integer coordinates in 5D intersect the line through P and Q. I do not have experience working in higher dimensional spaces, so my question and approach are naive. The strategy I am employing thus far:

1. Use a parametric form of an equation for a line in 3D as the basis for an equation of the line in 5D: `<p1 p2 p3 p4 p5> + t * <q1 q2 q3 q4 q5>`
2. Determine where the line PQ crosses the boundaries of the space in each dimension by setting the values of a point A to the minimum and maximum values for each dimension using the equation in step 1.
3. Iterate over the integer values of points in each dimension separately using the boundaries computed in step 2. This generates a set of points that are on the line.
4. Filter the results of step 3 so we have a unique set of points that are on the line, and within the boundaries of the space.

Questions:

- Will the approach I am taking result in the complete supercover of the line in this space?
- Is a more efficient way to perform this computation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to describe analytically the supercover of a line ($1$-flat) in dimension $n$. Check out [this paper](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00354197/document).

If you have a hard time understanding the paper or finding it, contact me: eric.andres [at] univ-poitiers.fr.